# Prolog syntax error on format

Tags: syntax, prolog, format, clpfd

I am getting a syntax error on my format line and i have no idea why!

```
magic3(Variables):-
   Variables[A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I],
   fd_domain(Variables,1,9),
   fd_all_different(Variables),
   A+B+C #= A+D+G,
   A+B+C #= A+E+I,
   A+B+C #= C+F+I,
   A+B+C #= B+E+H,
   fd_labeling(Variables),
   format("A=~w, B=~w, C=~w~n, D=~w, E=~w, F=~d~w, G=~w, H=~w, I= ~w", Variables).
```

The code prints

```
A B C
D E F
G H I
```

where all rows and columns are equal when added together
I can not figure out why I am getting a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In several systems you need to put at the beginning of your file/module:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

And as a tiny improvement you can introduce the sum `S`:

```
S #= A+B+C,
S #= D+E+F, % this too!
S #= G+H+I,
....
```

And even better, you can now calculate the sum with is (1+2+ ...+9) / 3 = 15. So add
`S #= 15`. There is a [nice animation on the Internet](https://www.google.at/search?q=clpfd+animation) for the actual labeling process.

---

Further:

```
Variables[A,B,...]
```

should read

```
Variables = [A,B,...]
```

Comment: that did not fix my problem. I have made other files the same exact way without includiing :- use_module(library(clpfd)). and I did not receive an error.

Comment: @onebadbaggins: Ah, seems you are using GNU-Prolog. Anyway, see edit above.

Comment: BOOM! good catch haha the missing equals sign was the problem!